# how to add and delete note in an iphone notes application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Is it possible to add or modify notes in iPhone notes application.. If any of you have any Idea regarding this means please share with me that will be very helpful for me. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Apple does not provide any API to interact with the notes app.

Comment: Do you have any Apple Developer Link that mention this thing?

Comment: Apple does not provide any documentation of things they have no api for. There is only documentation for the public apis.